# K&R exercise 1-18 gives segmentation fault when EOF is encountered

Tags: c

I've been stuck at this problem:

> Write a Program to remove the trailing blanks and tabs from each input line and to delete entirely blank lines.

for the last couple of hours, it seems that I can not get it to work properly.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int mgetline(char line[],int lim);
int removetrail(char rline[]);

//==================================================================
int main(void)
{
    int len;
    char line[MAXLINE];

    while((len=mgetline(line,MAXLINE))>0)
        if(removetrail(line) > 0)
            printf("%s",line);

    return 0;
}
//==================================================================

int mgetline(char s[],int lim)
{
    int i,c;

    for(i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
        if( c == '\n')
        {
            s[i]=c;
            ++i;
        }
    s[i]='\0';

    return i;
}

/* To remove Trailing Blanks,tabs. Go to End and proceed backwards removing */

int removetrail(char s[])
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; s[i] != '\n'; ++i)
        ;
      --i;  /* To consider raw line without \n */

    for(i > 0; ((s[i] == ' ') || (s[i] == '\t')); --i)   
        ; /* Removing the Trailing Blanks and Tab Spaces */

    if( i >= 0) /* Non Empty Line */
    {
        ++i;
        s[i] = '\n';
        ++i;
        s[i] = '\0';
    }
    return i;
}
```

I am using gedit text editor in debian.

Anyway when I type text into the terminal and hit enter it just copies the whole line down, and if I type text with blanks and tabs and I press EOF(ctrl+D) I get the segmentation fault.

I guess the program is running out of memory and/or using memory 'blocks' out of its array, I am still really new to all of this.

Any kind of help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

P.S.: I tried using both the code from the solutions book and code from random sites on internet but both of them give me the segmentation fault message when `EOF` is encountered.

Comment: ` for(i >0; ((s[i] == ' ') || (s[i] =='\t'));--i)` -- the `i > 0` does nothing.

Comment: In `removetrail`, the for loop condition is `s[i]!='\n'`, but if your line was terminated with `EOF` you don't necessarily have that new-line character. I'd not copy the newline and rely on the terminating `'\0'`.

Comment: Next line `for(i >0; ((s[i] == ' ') || (s[i] =='\t'));--i)` the first expression in the `for` can't be right. And you don't check for underflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy:

The `mgetline` returns the buffer filled with data you enter in two cases:

- when new line char is encountered
- when EOF is encountered.

In first case it put the new line char into the buffer, in the latter - it does not.

Then you pass the buffer to `removetrail` function that first tries to find the newline char:

```
for(i=0; s[i]!='\n'; ++i)
    ;
```

But there is no new line char when you hit `Ctrl-D`! Thus you get memory access exception as you pass over the mapped memory.

Comment: On Unix-like systems, you have to type Ctrl-D twice to trigger end-of-file in the middle of an incomplete line.

Comment: @KeithThompson this does not change the reason of segfault